Understanding the Harmonic Energy for Maps Between Riemann Surfaces？

I am trying to understanding this functional, the thing I got confused about is the meaning of term  $u_z\overline{u}_{\overline{z}}+ \overline{u}_{z}u_{\overline{z}}$ ?
Because harmonic map is almost comfromal I would guess it is the singular value ratio $\frac{\sigma_{\text{max}}}{\sigma_{\text{min}}}$ of the jacobian
$$ \mathbf{J}= \begin{bmatrix}
u_z & u_{\overline{z}} \\
\overline{u}_z & \overline{u}_{\overline{z}}
\end{bmatrix} $$
But I fail to show that.
